# Why does this Haskell complain about ambigous types when its extended?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

The following returns True (because 2147483647 is a prime).

```
length [f | f <- [2..(floor(sqrt 2147483647))], 2147483647 `mod` f == 0 ] == 0
```

Why doesn't it work when I try to extend it as below?

```
Prelude> [n | n <- [2..], length [f | f <- [2..(floor(sqrt n))], n `mod` f == 0 ] == 0 ]

<interactive>:1:39:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraints:
      `RealFrac t' arising from a use of `floor' at <interactive>:1:39-51
      `Integral t' arising from a use of `mod' at <interactive>:1:56-64
      `Floating t' arising from a use of `sqrt' at <interactive>:1:45-50
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

I don't understand though, why is a RealFrac arising from a use of floor? I thought floor took RealFracs and produced Integrals? Plus it didn't complain with the above example, I'm only inputting more integers as I did then.

```
Prelude> :t floor
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let’s un-obfuscate this slightly:

```
Prelude> (\x -> x `mod` (floor . sqrt) x) 2

<interactive>:1:24:
    Ambiguous type variable `b' in the constraints:
      `Floating b' arising from a use of `sqrt' at <interactive>:1:24-27
      `Integral b' arising from a use of `mod' at <interactive>:1:7-30
      `RealFrac b' arising from a use of `floor' at <interactive>:1:16-20
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

You’re using the value of `n` as a float, passing it to `sqrt` and `floor`. You’re then using that result as an int, passing that result to `mod`. The compiler can’t name a type with all those instances.

The reason it works in your first example, in other words

```
Prelude> 2 `mod` (floor . sqrt) 2
0
```

is because you’re using two different numeric literals. One can be an int and one can be a float. If you’re using the same value for both, you need to call `fromIntegral` to convert the int to a float.

You can get a different error message by adding a type signature, changing `[2..]` to `[2..] :: [Integer]`:

```
No instance for (RealFrac Integer)
  arising from a use of `floor' at <interactive>:1:52-64
No instance for (Floating Integer)
  arising from a use of `sqrt' at <interactive>:1:58-63
```

This might make it more clear that you’re using the value of `n` as two different types.

Answer (score -1):

**As pointed out by C. A. McCann below, my answer is not correct :-)**

As far as I can see, it's because the list you produce can consist of any instance of `Floating` since the type signature of `sqrt` is

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

By precomposing `sqrt` with `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`, you get the desired result:

```
    Prelude> take 10 $ [n | n <- [2..], length [f | f <- [2..(floor(sqrt (fromIntegral n)))], n `mod` f == 0 ] == 0 ] 
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
```

Comment: Haskell's type defaulting mechanism will generally handle that sort of ambiguity--just "any instance of `Floating`" will usually default to `Double`, for example. The error in the question is due to constraints that rule out all the possible choices of a default type.